# How do I read a Windows XP hard drive using Ubuntu on a cd?

Tags: boot, external-hdd, live-cd

I downloaded Ubuntu onto a cd and booted my laptop with it. When it was loading up it said something about checking filesystems. I just let it run until it was done. It then gave me an option to try Ubuntu or install it. I did the option to try it and it went to the desktop.

I then connected the HDD via this: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073SB3PD4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_glt_fabc_4RDNJHV129BM7DWHNKNC?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073SB3PD4)

The HDD model is this: Hitachi IC35L090AVV207-0

I opened Files to see if I could open and read the HDD but I don't see it in Other Locations. I then followed a guide and found that the name for the HDD I'm looking for is `sda`. I then ran `sudo fdisk -l` and then afterwards ran `sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt`. However, it returned an error that said `mount: /mnt: no medium found on /dev/sda`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was the device on sda ?   You need to adjust for your actual hardware?, ie. `lsblk` will list block devices (disks, partitions etc) or you could use `blkid` to view block device IDs...   The model of drive matters less (you gave very specific details on that) than the motherboard & especially settings in the firmware of your actual hardware (you gave no specifics on that, but we may not know your specific hardware anyway.. thus viewing details using commands is more useful such as `lsblk`, `blkid` etc)

Comment: @guiverc This is what shows up when I run those commands: https://imgur.com/a/IGxfUwg

Comment: There is no sda listed there is there, they appear to be nvnm0n1p9 (where 9 is the partition) but pictures are harder to read than text, so adjust for whatever is actually there.. and whichever partition you're trying to read (the *type* & details in the messages provide a huge clue).

Comment: @guiverc none of these seem to be the HDD I'm looking for though. I unplugged the HDD and ran those same commands and the list didn't change. Does this mean that Ubuntu isn't recognizing the HDD?

Comment: Yes it's likely your machine isn't reading the block device (disk), so I'd explore the SMART stats for the drive (ie. from the chips & electronics on the actual drive itself, which provide details even fi the disk itself is dead unless the circuit board on the drive is dead or without power, unplugged or other hardware like issue usually detected by operator); ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   You've provided no release details so it's generic advice; GUI tools can be used too